# Pandas add a series to dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to add a series as a new column in another data frame. But only 'NaN' is being added.

Series:

```
a_attack = df.merge(df_2,left_on = ['team_A','year'],right_on =['countries','year_list'],how = 'left')['attack']

type(a_attack)
Out[4]: pandas.core.series.Series

a_attack.tail(5)
Out[5]: 
38881    63.0
38882    80.0
38883    81.0
38884    59.0
38885    85.0
Name: attack, dtype: float64
```

Below is code that I'm using to add the series 'a_attack' to dataframe df.

```
df['A_attack'] = a_attack
```

But I'm getting NaN values only in the dataframe

```
df['A_attack'].tail(5)
Out[9]: 
38881   NaN
38882   NaN
38883   NaN
38884   NaN
38885   NaN
Name: A_attack, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['A_attack'] = a_attack.values
```

Comment: and how would you do if the name `A_attack` is in a variable?

Comment: you mean if the 'A_attack' is in a variable . You can use the same only

`var="A_attack"`
`df[var]=a_attack.values`