# What is the correct way to add a list as a column to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a list as a new column to a dataframe. I am doing:

```
df['Intervention'] = interventionList
```

It gives me

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

I read [Pandas add a series to dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152108/pandas-add-a-series-to-dataframe-column) where the accepted answer is very similar.

Comment: It means your `df` is originally a sliced dataframe. How have you ended up with it?

Comment: @AKX df = pd.DataFrame(index=mergeddf.index) then df = pd.concat((countryflagsdf, df), axis=1) .

Comment: Did either of these solutions answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I believe one option would be to use:

```
df.assign(Intervention = interventionList)
```

or to make a copy of the dataframe:

```
df2 = df.copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
import pandas as pd
li = [1,2,3,4,5]
li2 =[6,7,8,9,10]
df = pd.DataFrame()

#Using pd.Series to add lists to dataframe
df['col1'] = pd.Series(li)
df['col2'] = pd.Series(li2)
df
```